# How do I add comments to .gitlab-ci.yaml file?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I tried commenting out some lines from a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and the pipeline is failing saying the YAML is not properly formatted.

Below is the picture of what I see in the GitLab CI-Pipeline UI.

[image]

Below is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that is *error*.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
#  - release

build-demo-commands:
    extends: .npm-job
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm run build-demo-prod

include:
  - project: 'myproj/gitlab-ci'
    ref: '1.2.0'
    file: 'templates/npm.gitlab-ci.yml'
#  - project: 'myproj/gitlab-ci'
#    ref: '1.2.0'
#    file: 'templates/Kaniko-npm.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

I suspect that there is a pre-processor for the CI-pipeline which supports a comment syntax.

What is the correct way to comment out lines in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

## Searching for answer

- I found this [Add comments to .gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-design/-/merge_requests/44), which was merged two years ago.  Now I just need to find the page that says how to do it!
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/code_comments.html - not helpful
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#template-types -
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#explain-the-template-with-comments - Looks like the answer so why does it complain?
- [https://blog.wplauncher.com/add-comments-to-yaml-file/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20comments,line%20in%20a%20YAML%20file](https://blog.wplauncher.com/add-comments-to-yaml-file/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20comments,line%20in%20a%20YAML%20file). This says the `#` is the way to do comments.

## EDIT/UPDATE:

I believe the problem is with the included scripts and not with adding the comments.  When I removed the comments I still got an error.  The error was:

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
npm-deploy-snapshot job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre
build
test
.post
You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint
```

So I now believe that using the hash (`#`) character is the correct way to comment a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Comments in YAML use a `#` character which comments out the remainder of the line

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) says:

> Comments begin with the number sign (#), can start anywhere on a line and continue until the end of the line. **Comments must be separated from other tokens by whitespace characters**.[16] If # characters appear inside of a string, then they are number sign (#) literals.

Comment: The part about being separated by whitespace... That seems like it could bite someone. I think it bit me.